# Animated gif in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, animated-gif

There is a `gif` that animates a radar image I want to use in my openlayers 3 map.  I am defining the layer as a `ol.layer.Image`, and the source is `ol.source.ImageStatic`.  When I do this the radar does not animate.

I am assuming this is because I am defining it as `ImageStatic`, but I get errors when I try to add the image to the map with any of the other source options.

Does anyone know what I should be using for the source for an animated image `gif`?  Any examples of where this has been done would also be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a div to your html document.

   ```
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
    <div id="marker" title="Marker"></div>
    </div>
   ```
2. Configure your div with css to contain your animated gif

   ```
   #marker {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: url("http://netanimations.net/animated_earth_84.gif") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
   }
   ```
3. Add the div element to your map as an ol.Overlay

   ```
   var pos = ol.proj.fromLonLat([23.3725, 35.208889]);
   var marker = new ol.Overlay({
   position: pos,
   positioning: 'center-center',
   element: document.getElementById('marker'),
   stopEvent: false
   });
   map.addOverlay(marker);
   ```

and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr79m08g/) to see it in action

Comment: Thanks pavlos, but the problem is, this needs to be a layer on a map, for example a radar layer that conforms to the boundaries of the United States, not a div with a set width and height.

Comment: why dont you make a fiddle to show us your case. so we can guide you properly